# Daily Import of Excel Spreadsheets into Google Sheets

Tags: import, google-analytics, report

I have set up an automated daily export from Google Analytics to my Google Drive. So every day another `XLSX-document` gets added to the same folder, e.g.:

```
Analytics 20171220-20171220.xlsx

Analytics 20171221-20171221.xlsx

Analytics 20171222-20171222.xlsx ...
```

I now need a Google spreadsheet that imports that data.

The file looks like this:

[Analytics Report Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hslcV.png)

And I would like the Google Spreadsheet to look like this, with each channel having its own tab:

[Spreadsheet Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7CJD.png)

I've been trying add-ons like Supermetrics, Sheetgo and the official Google Analytics add-on, but none of them do what I need.

Is there a script template that can do this task for me?

Comment: In what way does the official add-on not what you need ? Remember that you can use the report as a data source - Google Spreadsheets are, well, spreadsheets, so you can use a lookup to insert values into the proper cells in your report.

Comment: I have defined a custom channel grouping in GA, which cannot be exported by the add-on. (It only supports the standard channel grouping).

Comment: Oh yes. That excludes any solution via the API.

Comment: Yes, and I cannot extract reports directly from GA (e.g. for monthly or even weekly reports), because the data gets sampled far too quick with custom channel groupings. This is why I wanted to collect the data on a daily basis and then aggregate it again later, as I need it.